# Can you resolve identity queries whilst Face API is undergoing training?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am investigating solutions for identifying people utilising facial recognition and I am interested in using Microsoft's Face API.

I have noted that when adding new people the model needs to be trained again before those people will be recognised.

For our application it is crucial that whilst training is happening that the model continues to resolve identify requests so that the service runs uninterrupted.

It seems to make sense that the old model would continue to respond to identify requests whilst the new model is being trained up but I am not sure if this assumption is correct.

I would be grateful if someone with knowledge of the API could advise if this is the case or if not if there is another way round to ensure continuous resolution of identify requests. I have thought about creating a whole new person group with all the new images but this involves copying a lot of data and seems an inefficient way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few manipulations on my projects using face API but the collection of faces is too small and the training is too fast to check. I think it's not blocking the previous version but cannot guarantee it.

Anyway, you will be interested in the following part of the documentation addressing the problems of training latency: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/how-to-use-large-scale#buffer

It shows how you could avoid the problem you depict by using a "buffer" group

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas. The link is definitely useful. I am going to leave the question as unresolved for now as someone with direct knowledge could show up.

Answer (score 0):

From the same documentation link in the previous answer:

> During the training period, it is still possible to perform Identification and FindSimilar if a successful training is done before. However, the drawback is that the new added persons/faces will not appear in the result until a new post migration to large-scale training is completed.

My understanding is that this would work with `LargePersonGroups` (hence "post migration to large-scale training") but is unclear if would work for the legacy `PersonGroups`.